# Modal popup backdrop remain after closing

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-modal

I have been working on a modal popup window where I display an image and make a tag over the image. The Modal works good and the image is displayed perfectly, but the problem I face is that when i close the modal with the help of the button, the modal backdrop fade in remains on the main window even after the modal is closed.

I have attached the code below:

Html: ( Modal)

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

<!-- The Close Button -->
<span class="close">&times;</span>

<!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
<div id="imagearea" class="imagearea">
<img class="modal-content" id="img01">
</div>
<div class="text_container">

  <br>
  <div class="input_tag">
    <span class="right_sec_text">Select a region from the picture</span>
    <div class="tags">

                    </div>
    <div class="input_box">
                                <input type="text" name="tags" class="input_textbox">
                  <button id="settag" class="btn_settag">Set Tag</button>
    </div>
    <div class="footer_btn">
      <p><button class="btn_success">Confirm Selection</button>
      <p><button class="btn_cancel" >Cancel</button>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Javascript: (for modal and the box over the image)

```
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById("imgside");
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
img.onload = function(){
modal.style.display = "block";
modalImg.src = this.src;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "none";
}

function preview(img, selection) {
        if (!selection.width || !selection.height)
            return;
        $('#x1').val(selection.x1);
        $('#y1').val(selection.y1);
        $('#x2').val(selection.x2);
        $('#y2').val(selection.y2);
        $('#w').val(selection.width);
        $('#h').val(selection.height);
        $('.img_error').removeClass("error");
    }

  $(function() {
  $('#img01').imgAreaSelect({
  handles: true,
  fadeSpeed: 200,
  onSelectChange: preview
 });
 });

$(".btn_cancel").click(function(){
$('#myModal').hide();
$('.imagearea').removeClass().removeAttr('style');
$('.modal-backdrop').remove();
});
```

Picture1: ( modal with image )

[image]

picture 2 : (modal after closing)

[image]

I tried removing the style and div from modal when btn_cancel button is clicked, but Its no working. Can someone help me with this problem.

Comment: I see this when the id of the modal has changed. Is your modal wraped in some type of server-side code?

Comment: @clamchoda yeah its inside the PHP code where I dynamically get the image inside the modal

Comment: move the header with the id outside of the server side code or make it static. Alternatively call `$('body').removeClass('modal-open');
    $('.modal-backdrop').remove();` after you click the close button.

Comment: @clamchoda I placed it outside the server side code, and still its not working. Can you show me how to make it static

Answer (score 0):

Unable to try replicating in JSFiddle without your img01 but with bootstrap modals you should hide with `$('#myModal').modal('hide')`

Source for reference: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/modal/#modalhide

Comment: when i use $('#myModal').modal('hide') its not working.